# how to solve this php laravel database problem

Tags: php, database, laravel

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'publication_status' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `categories`
>   (`category_name`, `category_description`, `publication_status`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (saiful, good human, , 2020-01-20
>   20:07:52, 2020-01-20 20:07:52))

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're not providing a value for `publication_status`, and your database is expecting one. So fix that.

Comment: You have 5 column names and 5 values, but the column `publication_status` is `not null` column, so you have to supply the value

Answer (score 1):

You need to either set a value for **publication_status** or modify the column in the database to allow NULL values.

To allow for NULL values you can create a migration by running: `php artisan make:migration allow_publication_status_nullable_to_categories_table`.

Then open the new migration file and add:

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //I'm assuming that the column publication_status is a integer
            //if not, just change it to the correct column type
            $table->integer('publication_status')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('publication_status')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }
```

Finally run `php artisan migrate`